# Is it possible to travel forward and backward along with time?

Tags: speed-of-light, time, faster-than-light

Is it possible to travel along through time if we found a thing that is more speeder than light?

Comment: No, it's not possible.

Comment: Yes, we can but just to the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually we can't reach to a thing that is more speeder than light. Because as we read in the Einstein's theory, the speed of light is constant.

When you reach the speed near the speed of light, the time will be stretched, and more you get close to the speed of light, more the time will be stretched and YOU WILL NEVER GET TO THE SPEED OF LIGHT.
So, due to this, it's clear you can't find something more speeder than light.

But about traveling through the time, my answer is yes but not as you said ( find sth more speeder than light).
you can travel to the future by getting close to the speed of light, because time passes more slowly at high speeds.
So, for example imagine you go to the space with .9 speed of light and after 1 year you come back and see on the earth it has been passed about 100 years!
So, with that in fact you have traveled in the future.